# Journey planner, graph data and Java

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, shortest-path

I am looking for a bit of help with some work I have.

The task is to create a London Underground journey planner.

**Edit:-**

At the moment I have an adjacency list of nodes with edge data in a HashTable.

I want to find a way to use Breadth-First searching to get a shortest path between any two vertices.

The vertices are connected logically as the tube map looks. Each station's edge is represent by using: (this_station, next_station, tube_line) <- this is the info I have about each station.

Traversing this is quite tricky. Any help seriously appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic graph theory problem. You can represent your stops as nodes, and your connections between stops as edges.

To directly answer your question, I believe the best way to represent segments of lines into a single line would be to make a graph which represents all lines. You can tag your edges with a data flag (or set of flags) to represent which line(s) the nodes belong to. Ultimately, regardless of lines, stations and segments, this is a graph. If you are interested in representing these concepts, the way I would recommend storing them would be as attributes of nodes (or edges).

If you are interested in removing these edges, you can iteratively remove edges which are purely intermediate. So, if A->B->C, and B has no other connections, you could remove B and add it's B->C weight to the A->C weight.

Using a graph representation will allow you to apply existing shortest-path algorithms to your problem.

Good luck!

-Brian J. Stinar-

Comment: Ok so the nodes are stations containing edge data about the adjacent stations for each line! If a node has only one edge then it is at the end of the line. I can follow the edge data to get a route... That's a great help thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I would think about the nodes containing edge data. Nodes can contain information about themselves, but usually don't contain data about the edges. The term I would recommend looking at is called an "adjacency list." This is a N by N matrix, where N is the number of nodes. If edgeA is connected to edgeB, the matrix has a "1" in the A-B cell. If AB, then BA, you only really need half this matrix. This is a good internal representation for a graph, which a lot of graph algorithms work on. You can also put weights in here, instead of a "1".

Comment: Ok that's interesting, I will need to do more reading. I'm not particularly interested in weighting the nodes. The shortest logical path is fine, rather than real physical distance/time.

Comment: If you use "1" this will mean shortest logical path in term of stops. However, if you combine nodes like described about, and you don't adjust the weights accordingly, there will not be any connection between your graph and reality. You can have a 'shortest' path in your compressed graph which represents nothing, because you did not take into account the compression.

Comment: Do you mean in terms of tracking the shortest path it is necessary to weight my matrix. I am at the moment aiming to use an adjacency list rather than a matrix.

Comment: It necessary to clarify what you mean by shortest path, and how that is reflected in your earlier goal of collapsing stops into lines. If you do not collapse stops into lines, you don't need to track any sort of weight. If you do collapse stops into lines, you need to reflect that collapse in the weights when you are calculating shortest paths. To provide an example, if you are tracking shortest paths in terms of stops, and you collapse 5 stops on a line into 2 stops, you need to reflect this collapse in your weighting (otherwise your shortest path calculation will not be meaningful).

Comment: Ah I see... after reading your answer I completely changed my approach and am using vertex and edge data. I have the graph and adjacency list established. I am now figuring out a Breadth-First algorithm approach to finding the shortest path between two vertices: https://blog.itu.dk/BADS-F2009/files/2009/03/38-graphs.pdf

Answer (score 3):

As [Brian implies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598351/journey-planner-graph-data-and-java/4598540#4598540), you'll want a weighted graph - the weight on each edge should be the time it takes a train travel between the stations at either end. However, that's not enough: you also need to account for the dwell time trains spend sitting at platforms, the time it takes to walk between platforms on different lines at stations, and the time you spend waiting for a train once you're at the platform.

Happily, you can do this within the framework of a weighted, directed graph. You just need to represent each station as a small sub-graph. To use Finsbury Park, the centre of the entire network and indeed the universe, as an example, you would have nodes for:

1. The entrance to the station (there are three, but you can just pick one)
2. A passenger standing on the southbound Victoria line platform
3. The arrival of trains on the southbound Victoria line platform
4. The departure of trains from the southbound Victoria line platform
5. Equivalents of nodes 2-4 for the other three platforms

You then have edges between them:

1. From the entrance to standing on each platform, weighted as the time taken to walk between them
2. From each platform back to the entrance, weighted in the same way (this is probably the same time, so you could just make this edge bidirectional)
3. From the arrival of a train to the platform, with weight zero (because it takes no time to step off a train)
4. Between each pair of platforms, with weight equal to the time taken to walk between them
5. From the platform to the departure of a train, with weight equal to half the interval between successive trains (because if you arrive on a platform at a random time, that's the average time you will have to wait for a train)
6. From the arrival of a train to the departure of a train on the same platform, with weight equal to the dwell time (as long as this is less than the half-interval, otherwise it will seem quicker to change trains at every station!)

You then connect each departure node to the arrival node at the next station down the line.

To plan a route from A to B, you find a path between the nodes for the entrances of the stations. The route will include not only the time spent on trains, but also changing between them. For many stations, you could consider many of the dwell and interchange times to be zero, but for some, they are significant: changing between the Victoria and Piccadilly lines at Green Park, for instance, or the dwell time on the Circle line at Aldgate. You should account for those, or you'll make the wrong plans for shorter journeys. You definitely need to account for frequency, too - it makes a significant difference between a plan featuring, say, the Circle line, where you can expect to spend three and a half minutes just waiting for a train to turn up, and the Central line, where it's only one.

One thing this approach still doesn't account for is the way frequency splits between branches. For example, you can model the wait for a northbound train at Tufnell Park as taking 1.5 minutes in the peak, but if you're going to Mill Hill East, you may have to wait longer, as most trains will be to Barnet. You probably need to add some time to the Finchley Central - Mill Hill East edge to account for this, but i'm not certain how well that generally applicable that is.

As for search algorithms, Dijkstra's algorithm will do, but [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) would be the classic option.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to represent the problem as graph problem and apply cost optimisations for shortest paths to solve the Journey Planner aspect of your problem. One common option is to apply [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Quoting the Wikipedia definition:

> For a given source vertex (node) in
>   the graph, the algorithm finds the
>   path with lowest cost (i.e. the
>   shortest path) between that vertex and
>   every other vertex. It can also be
>   used for finding costs of shortest
>   paths from a single vertex to a single
>   destination vertex by stopping the
>   algorithm once the shortest path to
>   the destination vertex has been
>   determined.

For Java you can find some interesting notes in [here](http://renaud.waldura.com/doc/java/dijkstra/) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/annas/)

An improved algorithm of Dijkstra is A* which performs better. Here there's a [project](http://code.google.com/p/jianwikis/wiki/AStarAlgorithmForPathPlanning) that implements it.

Answer (score 1):

This really is a separate question, so I'll try and give you a separate answer.

I think your choice of an internal representation of a hash might be messing you up. You should be able to still get things working using a hash, but if you look at the psuedocode on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)  for this, you notice that queues are being used for adjacency lists. I also try and think of adjacency lists as queues for this application. This makes it really more straightforward to get the adjacency lists per node, which is what you want to operate on under breadth first search. Then, if you want to change this to a stack, you've got depth first search super, super easily. It seems to me like you've read about this algorithm, and you have a general software development proficiency. This seems to me like an area that would trip me up if I were in your situation, but it could be any number of things.

Good luck!

-Brian J. Stinar-

Comment: Hi Brian, appreciate your response. I'm actually at the point where I am _nearly_ finished with the whole thing, at long last. It has been tough. I've got the whole thing set up around a queue as you suggested. Thanks again.